# Is there something like the SEQUENCE function in Excel in Libreoffice Calc?

Tags: excel, sequence, libreoffice-calc

In Excel if I have two columns and I want the first one to be an ID, e.g. and the second column to be a string. I can simply copy the sequence down. I can do the same thing in Libreoffice no problem. (like example below)

```
ID-1 | String 1
ID-2 | String 2
ID-3 |
```

But Excel will also allow you to use the Sequence function to only populate the sequence if another cell has a value. This is done like this:

```
-SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B0:B3))
```

Then I would get something like below, where ID-3 sequence isn't filled in because the COUNTA function returns false.

```
ID-1 | String 1
ID-2 | String 2
     |
```

I cannot find the sequence function in Calc and I wondered if it exists under another name, or if I need to do some more complex thing with IF statements?

Comment: AFAIK neither `SEQUENCE()` nor array spilling is supported in LibreOffice Calc. You'd do this the old-fashioned way and drag down.

Comment: Yes, I can drag down, but in the excel example the ID column is only filled in if there is a value in the B column. So I'm assuming I'll need to use an IF ??

Comment: Exactly @Rick Dearman. Something along the lines of `=IF(A1="";"";"String "&COUNTA(A$1:A1))` maybe.

Answer (score 2):

```
MMULT(MUNIT(SequenceLength);ROW(OFFSET($A$1;0;0;SequenceLength;1)))
```

resp.

```
MMULT(COLUMN(OFFSET($A$1;0;0;1;SequenceLength));MUNIT(SequenceLength))
```

depending on whether you need a vertical or a horizontal vector.

(Replace "SequenceLength" with the required length, of course.)

---

The problem is, that the usual matrix formulas treat any range-reference matrix as relative to the current cell. So I had to find a way to release the connection of a matrix to the cell range. Luckily, MMULT does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with the following.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1),"",CONCAT("ID-",ROW(A1)))
```

Although this is suboptimal compared to the Excel function, so I might write a SEQUENCE() function myself to allow for a more generic sequence.